# How do I profile an iOS application startup from push notification?

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I want to profile my iOS app when it starts up from the user swiping a push notification, from the not-running state.

How do I set up Instruments to attach to a particular app as soon as it starts up on the device (as opposed to starting the app via the "Profile" button in Xcode)?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the process target in Instruments to "All Processes" on the device and then filter down to just your app.

[image: profile all processes and filter]

I named my example app `test` in the screenshot above.